# Calculating limit of the given function.

Tags: calculus, limits

This question was asked yesterday.
The question is same but I am trying to tackle it in a different way. Calculate limit
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2(\cosh(x)-1)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}}{x^2}.$$
$$\text{Approach}$$
we know that $\cosh(x)=\frac{{e^x}+e^{-x}}{2}$ using taylor expansion for $e^{\pm x}$ we have $\cosh(x)-1=\sum_{1}^{\infty}(\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!})$  thus the original question changes to
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{2\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}}{(x^2)^{x^2}}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$$
putting $x^2=u$ we have
$$\lim_{u \to 0} \left(\frac{2\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{u^n}{(2n)!}}{u^u}\right)^{\frac{1}{u}}\leq \lim_{u\to 0} 2(\frac{u+u^2+\cdots+0}{u^u})^{\frac{1}{u}}=2(\frac{\frac{u}{1-u}}{u^u})^{\frac{1}{u}}$$ 
taking $\ln$ and simplifying we have $\lim_{u \to 0}\frac{1}{u}\ln(\frac{u^{1-u}}{1-u})$ I dont know how to continue from here. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are considering $$\lim_{u \to 0}\frac{1}{u}\log\left(\frac{u^{1-u}}{1-u}\right)$$ So, start with
$$u^{1-u}=e^{(1-u)\log(u)}=u-u^2 \log (u)+\frac{1}{2} u^3 \log ^2(u)-\frac{1}{6} u^4 \log
   ^3(u)+O\left(u^5\right)$$
$$\frac{u^{1-u}}{1-u}=u+u^2 (1-\log (u))+u^3 \left(\frac{\log ^2(u)}{2}-\log (u)+1\right)+O\left(u^4\right)$$
$$\log\left(\frac{u^{1-u}}{1-u}\right)=\log (u)+u (1-\log (u))+O\left(u^2\right)$$
$$\frac{1}{u}\log\left(\frac{u^{1-u}}{1-u}\right)=\frac{\log (u)}{u}+(1-\log (u))+O\left(u\right)$$ which tends to $\infty$.

Comment: the answer for original question was $0$ can you tell why my method gives a wrong answer.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar. I know but $0 < \infty$,

Comment: Okay so $e^{-\infty}=0$

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: Why "alas", is not it what needs to be proved? While the answer is true: $u\to 0^- \Rightarrow L\to +\infty$ and $u\to 0^+ \Rightarrow L\to -\infty$ and the latter is obvious from the LHS, however, I wonder if it is obvious from or applicable to the RHS (Taylor expansions)?

Comment: @farruhota. You are correct and I shall remove this *alas*. When I worked my naswer, the edit was bad and I was just able to pick the last part of the question. Being almost blind does not make life easy sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is fine. However, you must always keep $2$ outside of brackets and note $x\to 0 \stackrel{x^2=u}\Rightarrow u\to 0^+$.

Hence:
$$\lim_{u \to 0^+}\frac{1}{u}\ln\left(\frac{u^{1-u}}{1-u}\right)\approx \frac{-\infty}{+0}\to -\infty$$
and:
$$\ln L=-\infty \Rightarrow L=e^{-\infty}=0$$
as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer